# Video not working after website is uploaded through FTP

Tags: html, video, ftp

I built a very simple personal website and hosted it through FTP.

In the site, I have 2 videos I would like to play. Using the video control class in HTML, I put the video onto the site. Locally, my video plays fine. However, the moment I upload my website online, the videos stop working. I have double checked that my code is identical and the two videos are in my website.

Here is my code for the video control class.

```html
<div class="musicVidSub" id="musicSub3"> 
    <video controls class="musicVid" id="musicVid5">
        <source src="images/flute5.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
    <div class="musicDes" id="musicDesVid">
        Description
    </div>
</div>
```

If you want to check out the situation yourself, the site is ericamwang.com

If anyone could help me figure out why, that would be very helpful. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The folder on your website is spelled with a capital I. You must use

```
<source src="Images/flute5.mp4" type="video/mp4">
```

Windows does not differentiate between lowercase and uppercase letters in the file system, but Unix/Linux does. That's why it works on your local computer, but not on the web server.

Comment: Nevermind, I just noticed that they was a link to the website. Sorry!